# Android Runtime error on EditText.setText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a code that works on my PC application, but when I converted it into Android application, it tells me I have an error in setText methods.

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        EditText width = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        System.out.println("editText2: " + width.getText() + " " + height.getText());

        try {
            double _width = Math.round((Double.parseDouble(height.getText() + "") / IMAGE_HEIGHT) * IMAGE_WIDTH);
            String value = String.valueOf(_width).substring(0, String.valueOf(_width).lastIndexOf("."));
            width.setText(value);
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

});
```

Where I say `width.setText(value)`, I get a AndroidRuntime error. What's wrong with that? `IMAGE_WIDTH` and `IMAGE_HEIGHT` vary on the image and I've checked that they are initialized before using.

Comment: What is the value of *width* when it crashes? Is it *null*? (both the debugger and logcat will confirm this) This is important information to share. It would imply there is no editText1 on this particular content view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had set the EditText to only accept numeric values. In the code I was inserting a string. I had to change the string to an integer to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do a cross thread access. You need to invoke that calls.

You need to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). See also [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Create a `Handler` and call `.post()` with a runnable which sets the text for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like

```
String value = width.getText().toString();
```

And then just call

```
setText();
```